# How can I move the scrollbars automatically inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with large data. I have used `overflow` property to hide the extra data and now I want my scroll-bar to move automatically to the left to a position from where 4th, 5th, 6th element of 1st row and 4th, 5th, 6th, element of 2nd row will be visible. then after few seconds i want the scrollbar move more to the left so that 7th,8th,9th of 1st row and 7th,8th,9th element of second row will be visible

How it can be done. Is there **any javascript/jQuery plugins** to resolve my problem.
Here is my [`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/uL6t9/1/)

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Right? I was thinking "JsFiffle? Like it!" OP: Have you even attempted any efforts in finding out yourself? These might be the jQuery methods you're looking for: [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) [scrollLeft](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/)

Comment: On topic @Aadietya - do you want the box to come into view when the user clicks on it? You need to elaborate more on the behavior you want.

Comment: i want 1st, 2nd, 3rd image of 1st row and 1st, 2nd, 3rd element of 2nd row to display first inside the div. then after few seconds i want 4th,5th,6th element of 1st row and 4th,5th,6th element of 2nd row to be appear only in the div. then after few seconds i want only next set of 6 image to come in the div.

Comment: @Aadietya I've posted an answer of this on your [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16867774/1823761). [Check that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16890452/1823761).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**See this example on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z7kK/4/)

You just have to set the `.gallery` scrollLeft

```
var autoscrollTimer;

function cancelscrolling()
{
    clearTimeout(autoscrollTimer);
}

function autoscroll()
{
    var gal = $(".gallery");

    // don't cancel if it is the code scrolling
    gal.off("scroll");

    gal.animate({ scrollLeft: "+=" + gal.width() },
                function() {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        // when the animation ends re-add the code
                        // to stop scrolling if the user scrolls
                        gal.on("scroll", cancelscrolling);
                    }, 1);
                });

    // if still not in the end, continue scrolling
    if (gal.get(0).scrollWidth > (gal.get(0).scrollLeft + gal.width()))
        autoscrollTimer = setTimeout(autoscroll, 3000);
}

$(".gallery").on("scroll", cancelscrolling);

// starts the loop
autoscroll();
```

[To start over see this other version](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z7kK/5/)

Comment: i dont want the scrollbar to move completely to the end. i want the scrollbar to move to the left to a position from where 4th, 5th, 6th element of 1st row and 4th, 5th, 6th, element of 2nd row will be visible. then after few seconds i want the scrollbar move more to the left so that 7th,8th,9th of 1st row and 7th,8th,9th element of second row will be visible.

Comment: @Aadietya I've updated the code to do that, does it work for you?

Comment: yes, that worked. but after the scrollbar reached end i want it to return to starting point and continue the same

Comment: Actually it reached almost the end and you might have moved the scroll. That's a "little bug", run again and wait 3s after it reaches the end.

Comment: To fix it I guess you could add something to detect if the user scrolls manually you cancel the loop. I'm not sure how to do that, I could try something.

Comment: i waited for three seconds. the scrollbar is not moving back to its starting position

Comment: I've updated again, with that implementation it will stop scrolling if the user interferes with the animation

Comment: i checked the demo on jsfiddle. it's not working the way i want to. the scrollbar just stops inbetween

Comment: It seems that `animate` callback was called before it ended completely. So I added a `setTimeout` with 1ms, seems to be working.

Comment: the last line `autoscroll();` does not seems to work. once the scrollbar reach the end it never comes back to the starting point and continue the same animation

Comment: Do you want it to start over? Well, I made it so it would stop at the end. You can change and add an `else` to scroll to 0

Comment: yeah, i wanted it to start again.

Answer (score 3):

I think '`scroll="auto"`' should do the trick.
But you need to you place it in the BODY tag of the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can make the code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    lastElementLeft = $('.demo').position().left ;
    scrollAmount = lastElementLeft + 200 ;
    //alert(scrollAmount);

$('.demo').animate({scrollLeft: scrollAmount},1000);
});
```

and the demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/uaewc/307/